# java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset 2

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, client-server

When my Client (code below) sends data to my Server (code also below), I get the following SocketException
NOTE: The Client and Server are compiled into separate jar files.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Client Source:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Socket myClient = new Socket("localhost", 9998);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myClient.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("Testing");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            System.out.println(ioex);
        }
    }
}
```

Server Source:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(9998);
            Socket clientSocket = myServer.accept();
            while(true) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    String clientData = "";
                    clientData = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(clientData);
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
/*            while(true) {
                //Apparently, this will print a list of connections made... Useful in future?
                System.out.println(myServer.accept());
            }*/
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

I've found a solution and will post a link to the source I used here tomorrow.

Comment: Neither your client nor your server makes sense. The client never closes the socket, which will reset the connection under Windows, and the server keeps trying to read from a closed socket, which will throw a `SocketException`, because the `accept()` call should be inside the loop.